# Overloading an event handler with three additional parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to overload an event handler with parameters? If not, what is the best way of passing through an additional 3 parameters?

I keep getting the error message:

Here is a picture of what I am trying to achieve:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
    public bool DotControl { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    TextBox Tb = Keyboard.FocusedElement as TextBox;

    private void RemoveLastButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, bool DotControl, int Count, TextBox tb)
    {
        if (Tb != null && Tb != DriverTextBox)
        {
            try
            {
                var keypadObject = new Keypad();
                keypadObject.RemoveLast(Tb, DotControl, Count);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                TotalTextBox.Focus();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TotalTextBox.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void ResetButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, bool DotControl, int Count, TextBox tb)
    {
        if (Tb != null && Tb != DriverTextBox)
        {
            try
            {               
                var keypadObject = new Keypad();
                keypadObject.Reset(Tb, DotControl, Count);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                TotalTextBox.Focus();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TotalTextBox.Focus();
        }
    }
```

**Keypad.cs**

```
    // Backspace textbox
    public void RemoveLast(TextBox tb, bool dotControl, int count)
    {
        if (tb.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(tb.Text[tb.Text.Length - 1])) count = 0;
            else
            {
                dotControl = false;
                count = 0;
            }
            tb.Text = tb.Text.Remove(tb.Text.Length - 1, 1);
        }
    }

    // Clear textbox
    public void Reset(TextBox tb, bool dotControl, int count)
    {
        dotControl = false;
        count = 0;
        tb.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK event handlers have specific signatures - why don't you just call your custom method from the event handler? You can pass whatever you like then.

Comment: I think the `dotControl` and `Count` should be fields/properties

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - thanks, question has been updated, is my logic correct?

Comment: @Mashton - thanks, would appreciate an example

Comment: And how you expect to give these custom event args?????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event handlers have specific signatures, so call your custom method from the event handler. For example:

```
private void RemoveLastButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RemoveLastButton(DotControl, Count, tb)
}


private void RemoveLastButton(bool DotControl, int Count, TextBox tb)
{
    if (Tb != null && Tb != DriverTextBox)
    {
        try
        {
            var keypadObject = new Keypad();
            keypadObject.RemoveLast(Tb, DotControl, Count);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            TotalTextBox.Focus();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TotalTextBox.Focus();
    }
}
```

BUT from the example you have you don't even need to be passing those parameters (`DotControl, tb, Count`) to the new `RemoveLastButton` method because they are properties of your class anyway so accessible. Which means you don't even need to break out into a new method like this and can just put that code in the event handler as you had it, but without changing the signature of the event handler.